# Function uses initialised label.content and not the one I set

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm making a memory game and at the end I need to show a messagebox with the winner. Like: "PlayerName has won!" Like u can see in my code I'm trying to get the content of the "name1" label and "name2" label. When I start my game, the default content of these labels is "Player 1" and "Player 2". In my game I have 2 textboxes and when I click the "set" button, the names change on screen. So the content of the labels change. But if the game ends, the message box shows: "Player 1 has won!" or "Player 2 has won!" And not the names I set. How do I use the 'updated' content of my labels?

My MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
    private void setNames_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string userName1 = nameEnter1.Text;
        string userName2 = nameEnter2.Text;
        name1.Content = userName1;
        name2.Content = userName2;
        set1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        set2.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object AccessNamePlayer1()
    {
        return name1.Content;
    }

    public object AccessNamePlayer2()
    {
        return name2.Content;
    }
```

My MemoryGrid.cs (an other class)

```
    private void checkWinner()
    {
        MainWindow window1 = new MainWindow();
        object player1 = window1.AccessNamePlayer1();

        MainWindow window2 = new MainWindow();
        object player2 = window1.AccessNamePlayer2();

        if (scoreName1Tot > scoreName2Tot)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(player1 + " heeft gewonnen!");
        }
        else if (scoreName1Tot < scoreName2Tot)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(player2 + " heeft gewonnen!");
        }
        else if (scoreName1Tot == scoreName2Tot)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Gelijkspel!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are creating new MainWindow instances in the checkWinner method. These are unrelated to the one (or ones) that already exist, and of course have only the initial values of the AccessNamePlayer1/2 properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MemoryGrid class shouldn't access any Window for any data. It should be the other way around: Window updates data to associated classes (usually via Binding in WPF, but direct update will works as well).

so add two public properties in MemoryGrid for player names

```
public string player1 { get; set; }
public string player2 { get; set; }

private void checkWinner()
{
    if (scoreName1Tot == scoreName2Tot)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Gelijkspel!");
    }
    else
    {
        string winner = (scoreName1Tot > scoreName2Tot) ? player1 : player2;
        MessageBox.Show(winner + " heeft gewonnen!");
    }
}
```

and update them from MainWindow:

```
private void setNames_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string userName1 = nameEnter1.Text;
    string userName2 = nameEnter2.Text;

    memoryGridInstance.player1 = userName1;
    memoryGridInstance.player2 = userName2;

    name1.Content = userName1;
    name2.Content = userName2;
    set1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    set2.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

`AccessNamePlayer` is not needed

Comment: I implemented your code, but it gives me the error that memorygridInstance.player 1 & 2 are not existing in current context. Do I need to define them elsewere?

Comment: do you have an instance (variable) of MemoryGrid in MainWindow? I used "memoryGridInstance" name, becuase I didn't know, how it really called

Comment: I only have "private MemoryGrid grid;".

Comment: then use `grid` instead `memorygridInstance`

Comment: I changed "memorygridinstance" to "MemoryGrid" and that gave me an error that I needed a static field. So I changed "public string player1 { get; set; }" to "public staticstring player1 { get; set; }" and also did that for the other one. Now it works! Thank you very much!

Comment: I changed it to "grid" and it is giving me an error. "System.NullReferenceException"

Comment: @Johan, introducing `static` properties in this case is not justified.

Comment: It works now with a static, and it gives me an error when I use grid.player1

Answer (score 0):

You should call the `AccessNamePlayer1()` and `AccessNamePlayer2()` of the existing instance of `MainWindow`:

```
private void checkWinner()
{
    MainWindow window1 = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MainWindow>().FirstOrDefault();
    object player1 = window1.AccessNamePlayer1();
    object player2 = window1.AccessNamePlayer2();

    if (scoreName1Tot > scoreName2Tot)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(player1.ToString() + " heeft gewonnen!");
    }
    else if (scoreName1Tot < scoreName2Tot)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(player2.ToString() + " heeft gewonnen!");
    }
    else if (scoreName1Tot == scoreName2Tot)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Gelijkspel!");
    }
}
```